# Lagrange Multipliers, optimization question.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/iIHRu5Q) is the question. And here is my attempt at the solution:

$ h(x, y, z, \lambda) = 4x^2 + yz + 15 - \lambda(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1) = 0 $
$$\\ $$
The partial derivatives of h:
$$
\\ h_x = 8x - \lambda2x = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda = 4 (1)
\\ h_y = z - \lambda2y = 0  \Rightarrow \lambda = \frac{z}{2y} (2)
\\\\ h_z = y - \lambda2z = 0  \Rightarrow \lambda = \frac{y}{2z} (3)
\\ \\ h_\lambda = -(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1) = 0 $$

(1) = (2) yields:

$$
\frac{y}{2z} = \frac{z}{2y} \Rightarrow 2y^2 = 2z^2 \Rightarrow y^2 = z^2 \Rightarrow y = \pm z
$$

(1) = (2) = (3) yields:

$$
4 = \frac{y}{2z} = \frac{z}{2y} \Rightarrow 16yz = z = y
$$

if y = z (Result from (1) = (2))

$$
16y^2 = y \Rightarrow y = 0$$  or  $y = \frac{1}{16}$

If y = -z

$$16z^2 + z = 0 \Rightarrow z = 0$$ or $z = \frac{-1}{16}$

Therefore, the case where y = z or y = -z yields the same value in the end.

Case 1: y = z = 0 sub in $h_\lambda$

$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1 = 0 \Rightarrow x^2 = 1 \Rightarrow x = \pm 1
$$
Therefore, constrained critical point is at (1, 0, 0) and (-1, 0, 0)

Case 2: y = z = $\frac{1}{16}$

$$
x^2 + (\frac{1}{16})^2 + (\frac{1}{16})^2 = 1 \Rightarrow x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{254}}{16}
$$

Therefore, the constrained critical points are at ($\pm\frac{\sqrt{254}}{16}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{16})$

When I sub in the values of the constrained critical points back in the equation of temp I get:

$$T(\pm 1, 0, 0) = 19$$
$$ T(\pm\frac{\sqrt{254}}{16}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{16}) = \frac{4857}{256} \doteq 18.97 $$

My problem is that I get almost the same values for temperature from the different critical points and I know that something is not right. I'm not sure what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I was thinking that I also need to evaluate T at the boundaries which (I think) are (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) and (0, 0, 1). We already evaluate (1, 0, 0) so we don't need to do that. T(0,1,0) = T(0, 0, 1) = 15 but again, I'm not sure what that I am doing is correct or not.

Comment: when you get $h_x$ you are assuming $x\neq 0$ if $x=0$ you can not find the value of $\lambda$ by setting $h_x=0$ (division by zero error!). The same mistake appears with other variables, you divide ignoring the fact you may be dividing by zero ...

Comment: So should I add a restriction saying x $\neq$ 0 and do the same thing with other variables? Or should I have multiple cases, ie if x = 0, then you can't divide by 0 and the other case if x $\neq$ 0, then proceed to solve $h_x$ and repeat that process with the other equations?

Comment: multiple cases: a total of 8, x zero or not (2 cases), y zero or not (2 cases), z zero or not (2 cases), 2x2x2=8. But some of these cases can be dismissed almost immediately as some clearly will not satisfy the system (for example, all zero is not a solution)

Answer (score 0):

let us do in a simple way:

you want to find $f(x,y,z)=4x^2+yz+15$ with max, under $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

$f\le 4x^2+\dfrac{y^2+z^2}{2}+15=15.5+3.5x^2\le 19$, becuase $x^2\le 1$

so $f_{max}=19$ is no doubt,when $x=\pm1,y=z=0$.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how you got the inequality $f\le 4x^2+\dfrac{y^2+z^2}{2}+15$ and how did you get the inequality to equal $=15.5+3.5x^2\le 19$?

Comment: $y^2+z^2\ge 2yz \iff (y-z)^2\ge 0$, $x^2=1-(y^2+z^2) \le 1 \iff y^2+z^2 \ge 0 \iff y^2\ge 0 ,z^2 \ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the comment by  **Sergio Parreiras** , but I don't think it's necessary to run through eight cases.  Your Lagrange equations are correct, but one should be careful to perform "factoring", rather than "cancelation".  We have

$$ 8x \ = \ 2 \ \lambda \ x \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2x \ ( \lambda \ - \ 4 \ ) \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ z \ = \ 2 \ \lambda \ y \ \ , \ \  y \ = \ 2 \ \lambda \ z  \ \ . $$

Thus we have either $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ *or* $ \ \lambda \ = \ 4 \ $ (with $ \ x \ $ unspecified) and

$$ \ \lambda \ = \ \frac{z}{2y} \ = \ \frac{y}{2z} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2y^2 \ = \ 2z^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ = \ \pm z \ \ , $$

so your *basic* conclusions were correct.  In putting these together and applying the (spherical) constraint, however, we then find either

$$  \mathbf{x \ = \ 0} \ : \quad 0^2 \ + \ y^2 \ + \ z^2 \ = \ 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ = \ \pm z \ = \ \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \ \ $$

or

$$  \mathbf{\lambda \ = \ 4} \ : \quad z \ = \ 8y \ = \ 8 \ (8z) \ = \ 64z \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ z \  = \ 0 \ = \ \pm y \ \ \Rightarrow \  \ x^2 \ + \ 0^2 \ + \ 0^2 \ = \ 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ \pm 1 \ \ . $$

For the first case, the four "critical points" give $ \ yz \ = \ \pm \frac{1}{2} \ $ , so the surface temperature of the spacecraft at those locations is $ \ 0 \ \pm \ \frac{1}{2} \ + \ 15 \ $ , while in the second case, the temperature at those two (antipodal) points is $ \  4 \cdot 1 \ + \ 0 \ + \ 15 \ $ .  These then are the warmest points on the surface at $ \ 19 \ $ K .